# ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource using DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I am getting  ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resources using DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS. It is not happening daily but once or twice a week . I am using the Merge statement to update and insert the records . Is there a way to avoid this error ?

```
 DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.RUN_TASK (task_name        => l_task_name,
                                      sql_stmt         => l_sql,
                                      language_flag    => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                      parallel_level   => 4);


Trace file /u01/XYZ.trc
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.17.0.0.0
Build label:    RDBMS_19.17.0.0.0DBRU_LINUX.X64_220924
ORACLE_HOME:    /u01/app/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1
System name:    Linux
Release:    3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64
Version:    #1 SMP Thu May 18 11:23:40 UTC 2023
Oracle process number: 230

*** 2023-08-15T20:55:11.362843-04:00
*** SESSION ID:(1696.21009) 2023-08-15T20:55:11.362865-04:00
*** CLIENT ID:() 2023-08-15T20:55:11.362874-04:00
*** SERVICE NAME:(SYS$USERS) 2023-08-15T20:55:11.362879-04:00
*** MODULE NAME:(DBMS_SCHEDULER) 2023-08-15T20:55:11.362885-04:00
*** ACTION NAME:(TASK$_34836_1) 2023-08-15T20:55:11.362891-04:00
*** CLIENT DRIVER:() 2023-08-15T20:55:11.362896-04:00
 
2023-08-15 20:55:11.361*:ksq.c@13204:ksqdld_hdr_dump(): 
DEADLOCK DETECTED ( ORA-00060 )
See Note 60.1 at My Oracle Support for Troubleshooting ORA-60 Errors

[Transaction Deadlock]
 
The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. It is a
deadlock due to user error in the design of an application
or from issuing incorrect ad-hoc SQL. The following
information may aid in determining the deadlock:
 
Deadlock graph:
                                          ------------Blocker(s)-----------  ------------Waiter(s)------------
Resource Name                             process session holds waits serial  process session holds waits serial
TX-0004001D-0053AC1A-00000000-00000000        230    1696     X        21009     279    6509           S  39534
TX-005C0016-0023CB44-00000000-00000000        279    6509     X        39534     230    1696           S  21009
 
----- Information for waiting sessions -----
Session 1696:
Holds resource TX-0004001D-0053AC1A-00000000-00000000 acquired 46 seconds ago.
  sid: 1696 ser: 21009 audsid: 50982032 user: 106/USER
    flags: (0x8310041) USR/- flags2: (0x40009) -/-/INC
    flags_idl: (0x1) status: BSY/-/-/- kill: -/-/-/-
  pid: 230 O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 560
  client details:
    O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 560
    application name: DBMS_SCHEDULER, hash value=2478762354
    action name: TASK$_34836_1, hash value=3488044395
  current SQL:
  MERGE INTO T1 USING (SELECT * FROM S_T S WHERE ROWID BETWEEN :B2 AND :B1 ) S ON (T1.ID = S.ID) 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ....
Session 6509:
Holds resource TX-005C0016-0023CB44-00000000-00000000 acquired 41 seconds ago.
  sid: 6509 ser: 39534 audsid: 50982034 user: 106/USER
    flags: (0x8310041) USR/- flags2: (0x40009) -/-/INC
    flags_idl: (0x1) status: BSY/-/-/- kill: -/-/-/-
  pid: 279 O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 599
  client details:
    O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 599
    application name: DBMS_SCHEDULER, hash value=2478762354
    action name: TASK$_34836_2, hash value=2438080590
  current SQL:
    MERGE INTO T1 USING (SELECT * FROM S_T S WHERE ROWID BETWEEN :B2 AND :B1 ) S ON (T1.ID = S.ID) 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ....
----- End of information for waiting sessions -----
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS` instead of a normal pdml merge?

Comment: @PaulW  There are 5-6 mn records to be updated daily that is the reason I am processing the data in chunks.

Comment: You'd be much better off using normal parallel dml for this. That would significantly reduce the pathways to get yourself into a deadlock and would simplify your code. Simple enable parallel dml and hint: `alter session enable parallel dml; merge /*+ parallel(t1,16) parallel(s_t,16) */ into t1 using s_t on ...`

Comment: @PaulW Thanks Paul for the suggestion but problem is we can not process all millions rows at once because it may cause the delay in logical standby as primary db is replicated to secondary . We need to commit the transactions in chunks and we never faced any issues earlier  using DBA_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS  it started appearing recently .

Comment: It sounds like you're updating every row every time, even if it hasn't changed. rewrite the merge to join to the target within the USING clause and only find new or changed rows. That way in your update only changed rows are touched. That will vastly reduce the amount of redo and resolve your constraint with the redo replication to the standby. I'll provide you an example, but the space required will mean I'll have to be give it as an answer.

Comment: @PaulW Thanks Paul for the example. The T table is huge and contains 4.5bn records and merging in a single session may reduce the chances of a deadlock but it is going to take a lot of time to process I believe. It's difficult to update the entire script at once. I'm wondering whether there is anything that can be done with the code as it is now written.

Comment: My strategy is to *not* update all 4 billion rows, but only the rows that have changed. But I've also given you 3-4 other things to look at. Have you looked into them?

Comment: yes .. 1. No trigger , 2 . No Partition , No Foreign Key  defined , Not an Exadata, PCTFREE =10

Comment: I would really strongly suggest getting away from dba_parallel_execute_chunks and rewriting as I suggested. If all 4billion rows aren't changing every job run, you are working against yourself by doing all those unnecessary updates. And that procedure just adds further complication. But if you insist on using it as currently written, you're at the mercy of how that program works and whatever bugs it has. Apparently more than one thread is locking the same row. You'll have to open an SR with Oracle Support unless someone else has experience with deadlocks specific to this particular utility.

Comment: Is there a chance that a duplicate record is being updated or inserted by multiple threads if yes  then can we track that record?

Comment: @PaulW Also The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. Will the SR help ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255238/discussion-between-kashi-and-paul-w).

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your `MERGE` to only modify rows that actually have a change, your volume of redo will probably be much lower and won't pose a problem for your redo shipping to standby, allowing you to do the work in a single transaction. This will work much better than `dba_parallel_execute_chunks` and being a single session will greatly reduce the chances of a deadlock:

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;

MERGE /*+ parallel(t1,16) */ INTO T1 
USING (SELECT /*+ parallel(16) */ 
              T1.ROWID row_id,
              S_T.*
         FROM S_T,
              T1
        WHERE S_T.ID = T1.ID(+)
          AND (T1.ID IS NULL OR -- new records
               NOT (S_T.COL1 = T1.COL1 AND -- compare nonnullable cols
                    NVL(S_T.COL2,' ') = NVL(T1.COL2,' ') AND -- nullable strings
                    NVL(S_T.COL3,-1) = NVL(T1.COL3,-1) -- nullable numbers, etc.
                   )
               )
       ) S ,
 ) S ON (T1.ROWID = S.row_id)  -- use ROWID obtained above
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T1.COl1 = S.COl1,
                               T1.COL2 = S.COL2,
                               T1.COL3 = S.COL3, 
                               ...
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ...
```

In addition to this rewrite, you'll want to ensure that:

1. There are no triggers on the table. This would disable parallel dml and could contribute to a deadlocking situation depending on what it's doing.
2. There are no foreign keys on the table.  This would disable parallel dml and could contribute to a deadlocking situation.
3. If this is Exadata, you aren't using HCC compression (without the expensive ACO license to enable row level locking, HCC compression units (CUs) have only one lock bit per CU, drastically limiting concurrency. Concurrent updates will frequently deadlock in this situation).
4. Your data blocks have enough free space for ITL expansion. Make sure they aren't compressed with `PCTFREE 0` without override `INITRANS` to a much higher value than the default.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it must be the case that you have the same values for `ID` appearing in multiple `rowid` ranges.  This would be a problem even if you weren't having deadlocks, as you'd still have contention and unnecessary waits.

I would suggest that you break up your work by ranges for values of `S_T.ID` instead of `S_T.ROWID`.  You would use `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL` to do this.

Then your merge becomes:

```
MERGE INTO T1 USING 
  (SELECT * FROM S_T S WHERE S.ID BETWEEN :B2 AND :B1) S ON (T1.ID = S.ID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ....
```

Assuming `T1.ID` is a unique key, that should eliminate both the contention and the deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for responding !  are you saying instead of rowid I should use source ID between :B2 AND :B1 ?

Comment: also I am already using DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL (task_name   => 'T_ASK',
                                                  sql_stmt    => 'merge sql',
                                                  by_rowid    => TRUE);

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.  Make your chunks start and end values be IDs instead of ROWIDs.  Then you won't have multiple workers locking the same rows.  No contention, waits, or deadlocks then.

Comment: what should I mention in place of by_rowid in DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL (task_name => 'T_ASK', sql_stmt => 'merge sql', by_rowid => TRUE);